# Sending param values through Image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, parameters

I would like to send a parameter through the below given image tag to the contoller. How can I do that?

```
<%=link_to image_tag("del.png", :alt=>"Remove"), question, :confirm => t('json_message.are_you_sure'), :method => :delete%>
```

Thanks in adv :)-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the explicit `question_path(question)` route and then add whatever parameter you want.

e.g.

```
<%=link_to image_tag("del.png", :alt => "Remove"), question_path(question, :remove => true), :confirm => t('json_message.are_you_sure'), :method => :delete %>
```

This link will show up as `/questions/1?remove=true`